# Vertically center four responsive columns in css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am attempting to create a 4 column layout in CSS. Each column is the same width and contains:

A. an image
B. text related to the image.

These columns should collapse under each other one by one as the width of the screen shrinks; as well as expand back up to 4 columns next to each other when the screen expands. When all the columns have collapsed under each other (under mobile version screen widths) the columns should be centered in the screen rather than flushed to the right/left side of the screen.

The following snippet shows what I have so far:

```
<div class="sections">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/110x110"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/110x110"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/110x110"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/110x110"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>


.sections {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.sections div {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 0.5em 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    width: 20em;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like one being on top of each other as in being responsive?

Comment: I think you need media queries in your life. [Link to Google Developers about media queries](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en).

Comment: Take a look at this: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/. Will make your life easier.

Comment: @SleekGeek I do mean that exactly.

Comment: @dowomenfart I am aware of media queries however I should not need to use them for this particularly, unless there are specific things you can point out.

Comment: @Roope it is a very useful link however it is pretty broad, I understand these concepts however I believe it is the way I am displaying the divs that is being 'unresponsive'.

Comment: Don't use the `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.  Use `display: inline-block` and when the available width collapses they'll stack automatically.  No need to overthink this.

Comment: @JoshBurgess that worked! It totally missed my eye, feel free to post it as an answer otherwise I will do it myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If media queries won't help you just change `.sections` div display property value to `inline-block`.

```css
.sections {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.sections div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20em;
  padding: 0 0.5em 1em 0;
  display: inline-block; /* Thats all you need */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="sections">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/110x110" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/110x110" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/110x110" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/110x110" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That gets a bit closer however it doesn't do that responsive column shift that I described above. As stated by @Josh Burgess on the above comments, the actual fix was on display: table-cell to display: inline-block on the CSS for the .sections > div, as well as margin: 0 auto on the .sections class

Comment: you would be 100% correct except that the OP statement says: "(...) as well as expand back up to 4 columns next to each other when the screen expands. (...)". This code does achieve the columns stacked on top of each other, however it does not achieve the 'columns next to each other' part. If you change the answer to have display: inline-block instead, you won't have to rely in media queries.

Comment: anytime, I will accept your answer after it has been peer reviewed, thanks for your help regardless

Comment: It was a collaboration rather.

Comment: That's right, credit to @Josh Burgess for the record for the most accurate answer